# how to Hide Lotus Outlines based on User roles

Tags: view, lotus-notes, lotus

I am working on lotus applications, I want to hide the views based on certain roles. e.g Only Department manager can view the Lotus views not all users..
Another option that may be applied is to hide the outlines based on user roles .
can any one help

Answer (score 5):

It's been a long time, but here how it's done for hiding outlines with Formula language:

Select 'Hide When' option and add this line of code:

```
@IsNotMember("[MANAGER]"; @UserRoles)
```

Comment: Yep. I do it this way all the time.

Answer (score 2):

In the Security section of the properties of view, you can specify the rights to use the view.

These rights can be assigned to roles, groups or individuals.

When the view is not available for a user, the outline entry is hidden.

Attention : must be put the server, the server group and the database manager to have access to these views: Do not forget you.

Answer (score 0):

Each Outline Entry contains a Hide When Section, and you can definitely make use of the @UserRoles Formula to determine if the Outline Entry should be visible or not.

However, if a user knows how to hold CTRL+SHIFT and then click on the Top Menu "View\Go To", they'll be able to access the view that way.

I don't see this been too risky for what you want to achieve, unless it's sensitive data that's been shown inside the views?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Lotus Notes 8.5.3  and I was able to hide button when using formula like this

!@UserAccess(@DbName)="6"

I did not succeed with @UserRoles any more so I'm using @Useraccess to check if it's manager.  I also found out that I must compare value as string not number so.

Comment: Try using utkai's formula: @IsNotMember("[MANAGER]"; @UserRoles) and see if you can get roles working. Relying on access level is not nearly as granular as using roles.